# How to add string inside array using bash shell?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I'm using bash shell and have an array like this:

```
Numbers=$( one two three four five )
```

And I need to make it like this using sed probably but I'm not really sure:

```
Numbers=$(Numbers:one,Numbers:two,Numbers:three,Numbers:four,Numbers:five)
```

I tried it with some commands but the "Numbers:" only applied to first word and not all.

Comment: Looks like bash syntax. Are you using the bash shell? Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i Dont know if i understood what u said but

u have to push object inside your array for this case:

[{ 'Numbers' : 'one'},{ 'Numbers' : 'two'},{ 'Numbers' : 'three'}]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Good try, but I don't think @Swirlixx is using JavaScript, Python or whatever language this is.

Answer (score 0):

Question is unclear and confusing.

#### Converting `one two three four` list

```
echo "one two three four"|awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS=" "}{print "number:"$0}'


number:one number:two number:three number:four
```

#### generating an array from converted list

```
Numbers=($(echo "one two three four"|awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS=" "}{print "number:"$0}'))

printf "%s\n" "${Numbers[@]}"
number:one
number:two
number:three
number:four
```